# Generate varied values of some parameters over a neighboring interval

Tags: haskell, interval

I was recently tasked with creating a function that could generate a "varied" version of some collection of parameters. As in, it should take in a list of parameters, and then vary the value of the first one while leaving the rest fixed -- thus creating some variations.
We then move on to the next parameter, and repeat the same process (vary the one we are focusing on, leave other parameters fixed). This continues until we run out of parameters.
Parameters are "varied" by looking up an interval of multipliers in a Map, generating `num` multipliers in that interval, followed by multiplying the parameter by those multipliers to get its varied versions.

I tried solving this problem completely from scratch, rather than using some pre-existing libraries. My approach used the following

- A zipper so I could have a "cursor" to point to the parameter I was currently focusing on and varying
- Use the state monad to generate some variations based on the current state of the zipper, then shift the cursor,etc.

I do think my code feels rather overcomplicated and messy though, so I would like some feedback on how I could have done things better.

Further notes:

- I did use GADTs despite not being very well versed in them. This was because I wanted to impose the `Num` constraint for my RealInterval datatype.
- I feel that maybe an `Interval` typeclass was unnecessary.

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, MultiParamTypeClasses, FunctionalDependencies, BangPatterns #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor, DeriveTraversable, DeriveFoldable #-}

import Control.Monad.Trans.State.Lazy
import Data.Function
import Debug.Trace
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Data.Maybe
import Data.List

data Zipper a = Zipper {left  :: [a],
                        focus :: a,
                        right :: [a]}
              deriving (Functor, Traversable, Foldable, Show)

fromList :: [a] -> Maybe (Zipper a)
fromList [] = Nothing
fromList (x:xs) = Just $ Zipper [] x xs

toList :: Zipper a -> [a]
toList (Zipper l f r) = transfer l (f:r)
  where transfer [] l = l
        transfer (x:xs) l = transfer xs (x:l)
        
class Interval i where
  
  -- Generate a bunch of values in the interval, ranging from its start to end, with a step size specified by the 2nd argument.
  range        :: (Ord a, Fractional a) => i a -> a -> [a] 
  range i stepSize | stepSize == 0 = []
                   | otherwise     = go seed []
        where (trueStart, trueEnd) = endpoints i
              (incStart, incEnd)   = hasEndpoints i
              next                 = if trueStart <= trueEnd then subtract stepSize else (+stepSize)
              prev                 = if trueStart <= trueEnd then subtract stepSize else (+stepSize)
              start                = if incStart then trueStart else next trueStart
              end                  = if incEnd then trueEnd else prev trueEnd
              seed = if start <= end then end else start
              go !curr ls | not $ i `has` curr = ls
                          | otherwise    = go (prev curr) (curr:ls) -- builds list backwards
            
  -- Generate equally spaced values in the interval (as specified by the integer like number. Returns an empty list if negative, for now.
  linspace     :: (Ord b, Fractional b, Integral a) => i b -> a -> [b] 
  linspace i n = range i stepSize
    where (start, end) = endpoints i
          stepSize = (end - start) / fromIntegral (n-1)
          
  endpoints       :: Num a => i a -> (a,a) -- Get the endpoints of the interval (start, end)
  
  has          :: (Ord a, Num a) => i a -> a -> Bool -- Check for whether a number is within an interval
  
  hasEndpoints :: i a -> (Bool, Bool) -- Tells whether each endpoint of the interval is included
  -- bisect :: Num a => i a -> a -> Maybe (i a, i a) 
-- Attempts to bisect the interval around the provided value, if possible.

data RealInterval a where
  RealInterval :: Num a => (a, Bool) -> (a, Bool) -> RealInterval a

instance Show a => Show (RealInterval a) where
  show (RealInterval s e) = show s ++ " to " ++ show e

-- newtype RealInterval a = RealInterval {getEndpoints :: (Double, Double)}

instance Interval RealInterval where
  
  endpoints (RealInterval s e) = (fst s, fst e)
  
  has i v | prod < 0 = True
          | prod > 0 = False
          | otherwise = l == 0 && hs || r == 0 && he
    where (s, e)   = endpoints i
          (hs, he) = hasEndpoints i
          l        = v - s
          r        = v - e
          prod = l*r

  hasEndpoints (RealInterval s e) = (snd s, snd e)

shift :: Zipper a -> Maybe (Zipper a)
shift (Zipper l f r) = case r of [] -> Nothing
                                 (x:xs) -> Just $ Zipper (f:l) x xs


varyParams :: (Ord a, Fractional a, Integral b, Interval i) => M.Map a (i a) -> b -> [a] -> [[a]]
varyParams multipliers num params = case fromList params of Nothing -> [[]]
                                                            Just z  -> evalState genVar z
  where variations z = do let f = focus z
                          m <- maybe [] (flip linspace num) (M.lookup f multipliers)
                          pure . toList $ z {focus = m*f}
        genVar = do z <- get
                    let v = variations z
                    case shift z of Nothing -> pure v
                                    Just z -> do put z
                                                 rest <- genVar
                                                 pure (v ++ rest)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for the question!

This has been an interesting code review for me to do. The author of the code (who I presume is you) seems to clearly possess technical skill in programming, but perhaps is missing knowledge of Haskell idioms.

In no particular order, here are some comments:

- Some of the language extensions you enable are not actually used, like `FunctionalDependencies`. They are then just clutter and should be removed. If you run `ghc` with `-Wall -Werror`, it will tell you about unused extensions
- I would advise avoiding unqualified wildcard imports like `import Data.Maybe`. With more than one such import, it becomes difficult for readers who aren't using IDEs (like me!) to know where imported values are coming from. Prefer either `import qualified Data.Maybe as Maybe` or `import Data.Maybe (maybe, fromMaybe{-, so on -})`
- You note that you've enabled GADTs in order to include the `Num` constraint in your `RealInterval` constructor. I would generally advice *against* doing this. For any constructor with a constraint (such as `RealInterval`), we can remove the constraint and move it to callsites. This can be annoying, but means that the datatype is more flexible. What if you want a `RealInterval` of something which is not a `Num` (for instance, `Int`)?

  I can't remember where I heard this, but I believe that originally Haskell allowed constraints in types without requiring the `GADTs` language extension. It was decided that it was better to disallow this, and the feature was removed.
- Formatting: your formatting has a lot of unnecessary indentation. Perhaps this is intentional? If not, you can indent less as follows:

  Replace `do`, `case`, and `where` clauses that look like

  ```
  do a
     b

  case x of y -> ...
            z -> ...

  where x = ...
        y = ...
  ```

  respectively with

  ```
  do
    a
    b

  case x of
    y -> ...
    z -> ...

  where
    x = ...
    y = ...
  ```
- Formatting: more generally, your formatting is just very *strange* for Haskell code. This is not necessarily bad. It's up to you whether or not you want to conform to existing standards. If you do, I would recommend looking up a format guide or using an auto-formatter.
- Your implementation of `has` is pretty cool! In particular, I like the `prod` trick
- The `range` function can be implemented more simply as

  ```
  range :: (Interval i, Ord a, Fractional a) => i a -> a -> [a]
  range i 0 = []
  range i stepSize =
      reverse $ takeWhile (>= x0') $ iterate (subtract stepSize) xf'
    where
    (x0, xf) = endpoints i
    (h0, hf) = hasEndpoints i
    x0' = if h0 then x0 else x0 + stepSize
    xf' = if hf then xf else xf - stepSize
  ```

  Generally, your code makes me think you are coming from an imperative language. Idiomatic Haskell usually reads more as a description of what you want from the program rather than a sequence of steps instructing how to get it. For `range` particularly: "I want the reverse of the prefix greater than `x0'` of a list constructed by repeated applications of `subtract stepSize` to `xf'`

  This can be a strange and difficult transition to make. My only recommendation is to keep writing Haskell, and, in particular, read others' Haskell.
- You're using `where` clauses in implementations of function methods. I didn't know you can do that! Neat.
- You ask if the `Interval` type class is unnecessary. The answer is... maybe. If the only instance you're using is `RealInterval` then, yes, the class is unnecessary, because you can replace all uses of types `i` implementing `Interval` with uses of `RealInterval`.
- On the topic of typeclasses: typically* when writing a typeclass, one defines least number of methods require in order to encapsulate all desired functionality. Other operations, which are defined in terms of these methods, are not included in the typeclass.

  In your case, the `interval` class only needs `endpoints` and `hasEndpoints`: all three of `range`, `has`, and `linspace` can be placed outside the typeclass, because they are implemented in terms of `endpoints` and `hasEndpoints`. Note that you'll need to add an `Interval i =>` constraint to each.

  * The only reason I know of to violate this is to allow typeclass instances to provide a more efficient implementation of an operation

*Sigh* ... I had a lot more to say, but I had to reboot my computer and my work on this question got lost. I hope what I've said so far has been useful, and I'll offer one more thing:

Conceptually, the structure of the `varyParams` function is this: we have some things (ie, a list of `a`) and for each thing we have a number of ways we can vary it. A "variation of an `a`" can be expressed as an `a -> a`, and "a number of ways to vary an `a`" is then a `[a -> a]`. See if you can write a function

```
vary :: (a -> [a -> a]) -> [a] -> [[a]]
```

Which accepts a function `f :: a -> [a -> a]` and list `xs :: [a]`. The function `f` gives for each `a` a number of ways to vary it, and the list `xs` gives a bunch of `a`s. What is produced are the variations like you have in your original code.

This `vary` function exposes the structure of `varyParams` that I was talking about before. This should make the code more readable. Plus, generalizing is fun! (or at least I think so). If you can write `vary`, you should be able to also use it to re-write `varyParams`. That is what I had done; sorry that I lost it.

*Edit*: Oh, yeah! One last thing. Cheers to your use of Zippers! They are so cool.

Comment: Thank you so much for your feedback, it was really helpful!